# why using map is giving me the error( .map is not a function),it seems everything is ok in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, frontend

Since i am new on React JS,i tried to use map function but it gives me the following error:Uncaught TypeError: totalData.map is not a function.It seems everything is ok in the code,please provide me some feedback.Following below is my codes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';



export default class TotalData extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        totalData: [],
        isfinalData: false
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://nepalcorona.info/api/v1/data/nepal')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                totalData: res.data,
                isfinalData: true
            })
        })
}
render() {
    console.log("final data>>", this.state);
    const { totalData, isfinalData } = this.state;
    let finalData = isfinalData
        ? totalData.map((item, deaths) => (
            <div>
                <p>{item.deaths}</p>
            </div>

        ))
        : <p>Isloading</p>
    return (
        <div>
            {finalData}

        </div>
    )
}

 }
```

what may be the issue on my code ?
Following below are my fetched data from API and error i got:
[image: Fetched Data]

[image: Errors]

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: As you can clearly see in that output, `totalData` is an **object** not an array. Why did you think it *would* have a `.map` method?

Comment: Arrays/lists have `.map` method, not objects as pointed out by jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      totalData: [],
      isfinalData: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://nepalcorona.info/api/v1/data/nepal').then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        totalData: res.data,
        isfinalData: true
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log('final data>>', this.state)
    const { totalData, isfinalData } = this.state
    let finalData = isfinalData ? (
        <div>
          <p>{totalData.deaths}</p>
        </div>
    ) : (
      <p>Isloading</p>
    )
    return <div>{finalData}</div>
  }
}
```

you don't need to use map because you have only one object